# Is ChaCha20Poly1305 post quantum secure? is it better than AES-GCM or AES-OCB with 256 bit key?

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, quantum-cryptanalysis

I read online that AES-256 is Quantum Safe , so AES-256 used in AES-GCM and AES-OCB should be quantum safe , just wondering is ChaCha20Poly1305 quantum safe , if it is then is it better than AES-256 with GCM or OCB mode?

Comment: I would argue this is essentially a duplicate of [Security level of Poly1305 and GMAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/94974/security-level-of-poly1305-and-gmac) and existing ChaCha20 vs AES comparisons, like [XChaCha20 vs AES 128 security and speed](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/101050/xchacha20-vs-aes-128-security-and-speed/101056#101056) (XChaCha20 uses ChaCha20 internally, which was discussed).

Comment: Also, [Is XChacha20 - Poly1305 Quantum resistant?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/79518/is-xchacha20-poly1305-quantum-resistant?rq=1), [Post-quantum authenticated encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25741/post-quantum-authenticated-encryption), [Poly1305-AES vs AES-GCM](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/43112/poly1305-aes-vs-aes-gcm), and [Changing an Encryption scheme from AES to ChaCha20](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/88692/changing-an-encryption-scheme-from-aes-to-chacha20/88693#88693). The new bit is the discussion of OCB.